# Tensorflow 2.2.0 gather maximum elements over one dimension

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have the following problem:

I have a tensor of shape (1600, 29) and I want to obtain the maximum of axis 1. The result should be a (1600, 1) tensor. For simplification I will use a (5,3) tensor to demonstrate my problem:

```
B = tf.constant([[2, 20, 30],
                 [2, 7, 6],
                 [3, 11, 16],
                 [19, 1, 8],
                 [14, 45, 23]])

x = x = tf.math.argmax(B, 1) --> 5 Values [2 1 2 0 1]
z = tf.gather(B, x, axis=1) --> Shape: (5,5) [[30 20 30  2 20]
                                              [ 6  7  6  2  7]
                                              [16 11 16  3 11]
                                              [ 8  1  8 19  1]
                                              [23 45 23 14 45]]
```

Okay, now, x gives me the maximum element over my axis, however, tf.gather does not return [30, 7, 16, 19, 45], but some weird tensor. How do I "reduce" the dimension properly?

My "rather" dirty way is this:

```
eye_z = tf.eye(5, 5)

intermed_result = z*eye_z

result = tf.linalg.matvec(intermed_result,tf.transpose(tf.constant([1,1,1,1,1], dtype=tf.float32)))
```

Which results in the correct tensor: `[30.  7. 16. 19. 45.]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have [`tf.math.reduce_max`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/reduce_max) for this:

```
m = tf.math.reduce_max(B, axis=1)

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
sess.run(m)
# array([30,  7, 16, 19, 45])
```

Comment: But I also need the indexes. Does this mean the best way of achieving this is tf.math.argmax and tf.math.reduce_max?

Comment: To use the index returned by argmax, you may look into `tf.gather_nd` @marvi